# start an Activity behind another Activity for transition animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

For my App I am trying to reveal the actual `ContentActivity` behind a before-shown-`IntroActivity`. I would love to build the feeling of ContentActivity being behind the IntroActivity and then the IntroActivity disappearing to the bottom, with the ContentActivity already behind it.

I have tried `overridePendingTransition()`, which is not working for me here. Starting `ContentActivity` is called from `IntroActivity`right now and looks like this:

```
    private void startContentActivity() {
        ContentActivity.launch(this);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.do_not_move, R.anim.disappear_to_bottom);
    }
```

When I change the animation to

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear_from_left, R.anim.disappear_to_right);
```

it is working as expected (ContentActivity enters from the right and IntroActivity leaves to the right). However, the first snippet results in no transition animation at all.

For a better understanding, here are the animation resources:

**R.anim.do_not_move**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.disappear_to_bottom**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@integer/main_animations_timing" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.disappear_to_right**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@integer/main_animations_timing" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.appear_from_left**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@integer/main_animations_timing" />
</set>
```

Does anybody have an idea? Should I start the ContentActivity before or is there a better way to achieve this?